# Who was the writer of the Vishnu Sahasranamam?

Tags: mahabharata, bhishma, vishnu-sahasranama

I know that *Vishnu Sahasranamam* was told by Pitamaha Bhishma to Yudhishthira *ORALLY*. However who was the writer and who had made the hard copy of the same to do chanting of this mantra and when?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why Bhishma wrote Vishnu Sahasranama stotram?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/27637/why-bhishma-wrote-vishnu-sahasranama-stotram)

Comment: @cr241: Apologies for not duplicate...

Comment: @CR241 it's not a duplicate; it is similar. OP is asking "who was the writer and making a hard copy...". The link you gave discusses "Why he wrote it..".

Comment: Vyasa is the author of Mahabharata. Vishnu sahasranama is part of Mahabharata. So Vyasa is the author of Vishnu sahasranama.

Answer (score 5):

As you have already stated in the question, Bhishma told Vishnu Sahasranama to Pandavas. To be more precise, it was Yudhushtira who asked for it. The names present in the stotra are the most famous names of Lord Vishnu which were already sung by great men and rishis.

> yāni nāmāni gauṇāni vikhyātāni mahātmanaḥ|
>       ṛṣibhiḥ parigītāni tāni vakṣyāmi bhūtayē ||
>
> I am giving for the benefit of all, those names of His which are far-famed, which are indicative of His attributes, and which find a place in the exalted hymns of the ṛṣis.

To answer your question who composed those names into a hard copy, it is the same one who wrote the Mahabharata i.e **Veda Vyasa** because these are part of the Mahabharata itself. This is made clear in the Anga nyaasa of the stotra (installing deity in our body). Every mantra has a rishi (seer), chandas (metre), deity.

> Asya śrī viṣṇu-sahasranāma-stotra mahā mantrasya
>
> **śrī vedavyāso bhagavān ṛṣiḥ**
>
> For this great sacred chant "Thousand names of Vishnu", **Sri Veda Vyasa is the divine rishi**.

So, the answer is Veda Vyasa.

Comment: Ganesha is Scribe (लेखक) of Mahabharata... https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/22412/12304 so answer to "making of hard copy" should be Ganesha I believe... Composer, Narrator or Rishi of Mantras is well covered in ur answer...

Comment: @YDS , this argument can't be bought. With this logic, if a famous script writer employs an assistant to pen the book as told, then the assistant becomes the writer with all credit. The book after being published, should bear assistant's name. Sounds weird, doesn't it?

Comment: @Vineet महाभारत के रचयिता – वेदव्यास जी... लेखक - गणेश जी... that's what I know...now this fact should be mentioned like actors names are mentioned alongwith director...i don't think ur *assistant logic* is completely valid here...

Comment: @YDS The question is who is the writer. Vyasa is the writer. Ganesha is the scribe but it doesn't mean he wrote. Rachayita means a writer. Ganesh is publisher here. I will consider Vyasa as writer because he is the one composed and seer of the stotra.

Comment: @YDS , suppose you conceptualized a great book, employed me for jotting it down or publishing. Then who becomes the writer? Whose name should appear on the cover? YDS or Vineet? :-)